# Can Html.RenderAction be used as ASP.NET MVC 2.0's "donut caching"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm not at a development system where I can test this. If I output cache a view, and inside that view have a Html.RenderAction that loads some html from a separate action, would that newly pulled in HTML be cached or would Html.RenderAction run every time, thus acting as donut caching for ASP.NET MVC 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this does not get you donut caching. The complete result of the action is cached.

I think there is no way for donut caching in ASP.NET MVC2. Hopefully it is high on the list of todos of Scott Guthrie  and his team